# changing font size automatically

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, vb.net

I have 3 paragraphs of text on a page...**I want to change the font size of the paragraphs after every 3 seconds**....is this possible?
 
    What i want is when the page loads para 1 is 10px and  para 2 is 8px and then after 3 seconds para 2 is 10px and para 1 is  8px.

I mean like using an update panel or something? js ...any way?

Comment: off topic But don't you think it would be distracting

Comment: ya i know..but my client is insisting a lot..cant help...any idea how can i do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setInterval` method to run a function at an interval:

CSS:

```
#para1 { font-szie: 10px; }
#para2 { font-szie: 8px; }
#para3 { font-szie: 8px; }
```

HTML:

```
<p id="para1">asdf</p>
<p id="para2">asdf</p>
<p id="para3">asdf</p>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var current = 0;
  var ids = ['para1', 'para2', 'para3'];
  window.setInterval(function(){
    current = (current + 1) % 3;
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.fontSize = (i == current ? '10px' : '8px');
    }
  }, 3000);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div>
<p id="p1">Para1  </p>
<p id="p2">Para2  </p>
</div>
```

```
 $(function() {
        var pa1 = 20, pa2 = 8, pa3;
        $('#p1').css('fontSize', pa1);
        $('#p2').css('fontSize', pa2);
        function fstyle() {
                pa3 = pa1;
                pa1 = pa2;
                pa2 = pa3;
                $('#p1').css('fontSize', pa1);
                $('#p2').css('fontSize', pa2);
                            }
            setInterval(fstyle, 3000);
        });
```